# How do I get the query result's headers from asynchronous query using BigQuery client?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am using Google Cloud Client Libraries for Python [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) to make an SQL query to BigQuery. I want to be able to write the query results into a csv file which also includes the query result headers.

I am using the code snippet below to make the asynchronous query:

```
job = bigquery_client.run_async_query(job_name, sql_query)
query_results = job.result()
data = query_results.fetch_data() # returns an iterator to the query result data, this is successful
schema = query_results.schema # returns ()
print(schema)
```

I was able to retrieve the query result data. My plan to extract the query result headers was by first getting the schema of the query result table. However, when I attempted to use `query_results.schema`, it returns me an empty tuple `()`. From [this 
documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/_modules/google/cloud/bigquery/query.html), it is mentioned that the schema is `None until set by server`. How do I trigger the server to set the schema correctly?

Thank you for your help.

Note: I had no problem getting the `query_result.schema` if the query is synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a method. Apparently I need to reload the destination table of the asynchronous query job.

```
destination_table = query_job.destination
destination_table.reload()
schema = destination_table.schema # schema is reloaded correctly!
```

Thank you.